# get value from form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

I'm using rails 4.0.1

```
<%= form_for @event, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :place_id %><br>
    <%= f.collection_select(:place_id, @places, :id, :title) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And I want to check for current_user.id and Place.user_id (it stores creator id). In Events cotroller i'm trying to use:

```
def create
  @places = Place.all
  @event = Event.new(event_params)
  @event.user_id = current_user.id
  @curplace = Place.find_by(id: params[:place_id])
  @event.content = @curplace.id 
  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save
      format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

But i got an error. I think i'm not getting this Place_id param right or anything else?

Comment: yes you are right. Use params[:event][:place_id] instead params[:place_id].

Comment: @AnkushKataria thanks. it's working great! And a Happy new year :)

Comment: I'm writing answer to explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Further to the comment from Ankush Kataria, the `form_for` helper basically creates a form which combines all the params into a hash, as opposed to `form_tag`, which just makes the params independently

As you've discovered, this means your params will be accessed by:

```
#form_for
params[:variable][:param]

#form_tag
params[:param]
```

---

**form_for**

The reason why this is important is because if you're using the `RESTful` routes interface, you'll be able to `create` / `edit` / `update` a variety of records

`form_for` basically keeps consistency throughout this process, pre-populating your forms with the various values, and keeping your code DRY

To call a `form_for` helper, you have to define the `@varaible` the form will populate. This `@variable` needs to be an `ActiveRecord` object, and is why you have to build it in the `new` action before your form shows

---

**form_tag**

`form_tag` is much more independent of the `form_for` helper, doesn't require any `@variable`, and creates the params individually

You'd use a `form_tag` for the likes of a `contact us` form or similar

---

**Your Code**

Your form looks good, but your `create` action can be dried up:

```
def create
  @places = Place.all
  @event = Event.new(event_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @event.save
      format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private 
def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:title, :content).merge(user_id: current_user.id, place_id: params[:event][:place_id])
end
```

Comment: thanks! Where was your answer, when i maded likes? :) I managed to make them with a link and a method in controllers. It's really very simple.

Comment: You're welcome! The best thing is to make your code as DRY as possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You are right that params[:place_id] isn't returning the value you expect. It only returns nil. To get the :place_id that's submitted by the form, you have to do this:

```
@curplace = Place.find(params[:event][:place_id])
```

Just replace the old line with the code above. It's because your form submits the data in the fields inside an :event key in the params hash since you're using the form_for helper method provided by Rails. That is its default behavior unless you change the 'name' attribute's value in the input fields.

Hope that helps!